# Predicting House Prices on Kaggle not able to test existing data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle

I am trying to solve the Kaggle housing problem and am new to Python. Below is my attempt at it, but I'm unable to figure out why the data is not being processed even though I can retrieve and view the data. When I try to view the information in the train_loader, I did manage to see some numbers in it, but the result that is getting printed out is always "fold 0, train rmse: -0.000000, valid rmse: -0.000000"

```
class MLP(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, inputSize=3, outputSize=10, lr=0.01, weight_decay=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(inputSize, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, outputSize),
        )
        self.lr = lr
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay

    def forward(self, X):
        return self.layers(X)

    def loss(self, y_hat, y):
        fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        return fn(y_hat, y)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), self.lr, weight_decay=self.weight_decay)

class Trainer:

  def __init__(self, n_epochs = 3):
    self.max_epochs = n_epochs    
    self.epoch_losses = []
    self.accuracies = []
    return

  def fit(self, model, train_loader, val_loader):
    
    self.data = train_loader

    self.optimizer = model.configure_optimizers()
    self.model     = model

    for epoch in range(self.max_epochs):
          avr_epoch_loss = self.fit_epoch()
          print(f'Avarage loss after each epoch {epoch}: {avr_epoch_loss}')
          self.epoch_losses.append(avr_epoch_loss)

          accuracy = self.validate(model, val_loader)
          print(f'Accuracy each epoch {epoch}: {accuracy}')
          self.accuracies.append(accuracy)


    print("Training process has finished")

  def fit_epoch(self):
    current_loss = 0.0
    all_losses = []
    for i, data in enumerate(self.data):
      inputs, target = data
      self.optimizer.zero_grad()
      outputs = self.model(inputs)
      loss = self.model.loss(outputs, target)
      all_losses.append(loss.item())
      loss.backward()
      self.optimizer.step()
      current_loss += loss.item()
      if i % 500 == 499:
          print('Loss after mini-batch %5d: %.3f' %(i + 1, current_loss / 500))
          current_loss = 0.0

    return sum(all_losses)/len(all_losses)
  def validate(self, model, val_loader):
    model.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
      for data in val_loader:
        inputs, targets = data[0], data[1]
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == targets).sum().item()
    accuracy = correct/total
    return accuracy
    

def get_k_fold_data(k, i, X, y):
    assert k > 1
    fold_size = X.shape[0] // k
    X_train, y_train = None, None
    for j in range(k):
        idx = slice(j * fold_size, (j + 1) * fold_size)
        X_part, y_part = X[idx, :], y[idx]
        if j == i:
            X_valid, y_valid = X_part, y_part
        elif X_train is None:
            X_train, y_train = X_part, y_part
        else:
            X_train = torch.concat((X_train, X_part), dim=0)
            y_train = torch.concat((y_train, y_part), dim=0)
    return X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid


def k_fold(k, X_train, y_train, num_epochs, learning_rate, weight_decay, batch_size):
    train_l_sum, valid_l_sum = 0, 0
    for i in range(k):
        X_train_fold, y_train_fold, X_valid_fold, y_valid_fold = get_k_fold_data(k, i, X_train, y_train)
        mlp_model = MLP(inputSize=X_train.shape[1], outputSize=1, lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay)
        trainer = Trainer(num_epochs)

        # Create a data loader for the training data
        trainset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)

        train_size = int(0.8 * len(trainset))
        val_size = len(trainset) - train_size
        train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(trainset, [train_size, val_size])

        train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
        val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
        # Train the model
        trainer.fit(mlp_model, train_loader, val_loader)

        # Evaluate the model on the validation data
        with torch.no_grad():
            mlp_model.eval()
            y_train_pred = mlp_model(X_train_fold)
            train_loss = mlp_model.loss(y_train_pred, y_train_fold)

            y_valid_pred = mlp_model(X_valid_fold)
            valid_loss = mlp_model.loss(y_valid_pred, y_valid_fold)

            train_l_sum += train_loss.item()
            valid_l_sum += valid_loss.item()

            print('fold %d, train rmse: %f, valid rmse: %f' % (i, train_loss.item(), valid_loss.item()))

    return train_l_sum / k, valid_l_sum / k
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from your description exactly what you are trying to do with your model. I am assuming you are trying to predict house prices.

First of all, house price prediction is a regression problem and commonly used cost/loss function for regression problems are MSE, RMSE, MAE, etc. I noticed that under the *'kfold'* function where you are running the training loop, you are printing out RMSE at the validation stage which leads to my assumption that you are trying to predict house prices. However, you defined your loss function to be a cross entropy loss which is primarily used for classification problems (e.g. classifying house color, pattern, or other details).

You need to replace the following:

```
def loss(self, y_hat, y):
    fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    return fn(y_hat, y)
```

with this (to get RMSE loss):

```
def loss(self, y_hat, y):        
    return torch.sqrt(torch.mean((yhat-y)**2))
```

or with this (to get MSE loss):

```
def loss(self, y_hat, y):
    fn = nn.MSELoss()
    return fn(y_hat, y)
```

Secondly, your *validate* function would not yield proper result (in fact no result at all) as you are applying Softmax here to ultimately calculate accuracy. Since in regression problem we deal with continuous variables/labels, it is not ideal (or realistically possible) to calculate accuracy in such cases. Hence, your loss function is the primary evaluation metric here unless the problem requires you to evaluate with any other specific metric.